# Не удаётся считать двумерный массив из файла (заполняется нулями)

Tags: c, динамические-массивы

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define int64 long long int;

int height(FILE*); //Функция получения высоты
int width(FILE*); //Функция получения ширины

int isNotSquare(FILE*, int*); //Функция проверки на квадратичность матрицы

double ** create(int); //Функция создания буфферного массива
void readfromfile(FILE *, double **, int); //Функция считывания с файла

void erase(double **, int);


int main(void)
{
    char fname[256]; //Массив под имя файла
    scanf("%[^\n]",fname);
    FILE* input;
    if((input=fopen(fname, "r"))==NULL) //Открываем файл для чтения и проверяем на ошибку ввода
    {
        printf("Error opening file");
        exit(1); 
    } 
    int clsnum; //Количество строк/столбцов
    if(isNotSquare(input, &clsnum)) //Проверка на квадратичность
    { 
        printf("Fail");
        fclose(input);
        return 0;
    } 
    double **buff;
    if((buff=create(clsnum))==NULL) //Создаём буферный массив под матрицу
    {
        printf("Sorry, but i can't give you any memory");
        fclose(input);
        return 2;
    }
    readfromfile(input, buff, clsnum);
    for(int i=0; i<clsnum; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<clsnum; j++)
            printf("%f ", buff[i][j]);
    return 0;   
}

int height(FILE* file)
{
    int height=0;
    while (!feof(file))
        if (fgetc(file) == '\n')
           height++;
    return height+2;
}

int width(FILE* file)
{
    int width=0;
    char c;
    while((c=fgetc(file))!=('\n'))
        if(c!=' ')
            width++;
    return width-1;
}

int isNotSquare(FILE* input, int *clsnumber)
{
    int w = 0;
    int h = 0;
    w = width(input);
    h = height(input);
    printf("%d%d", w, h);
    if (w!=h)
        return 1; 
    *clsnumber=w;
    return 0;
}

void readfromfile (FILE * fp, double ** p, int num)
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<num;i++)
        for(j=0;j<num;j++)
            fscanf(fp,"%lf",&p[i][j]);
}

double ** create(int num)
{
    double ** temp = (double **) malloc(num * sizeof(double *));    //Здесь и далее - некомментируемые 
    for (int i=0; i<num; i++)                                      //действия считаются очевидными - и не
        temp[i] = (double *) malloc(num * sizeof(double));        //нуждаются в комментировании.
    return temp;   
}

void erase(double ** p, int num)
{
    for (int i=0; i<num; i++)
        free(p[i]);
    free(p);
}
```

Собственно на вход подаётся txt файл содержащий n чисел через пробел, надо считать его в массив и вывести на экран. Не могу понять где накосячил с вводом, весь массив в итоге нули

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы все время читаете файл с начала до конца, но не возвращаетесь в начало.

И нигде не проверяете успешность чтения - иначе бы сразу сами нашли ошибку...

И еще - учтите, что `feof()` вернет `true` только *после неудачного чтения за концом файла*, но не ранее...

Comment: Не сразу понял о чём вы, благодарю, проблема из-за того, что после определения квадратичности указатель оставался в конце